# Vue: Update data from component to component

Tags: vue.js

i have a master layout named Main.vue and a view named Dashboard.vue, this is Main.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="app">
      <div class="loading" v-if="loading">
        <square-loader :loading="true" color="#26A65B" size="50px"></square-loader>
      </div>

        <div class="container-fluid">
          <router-view></router-view><!--Dashboard.vue will be rendered here-->
        </div>
</template>
<script>
import SquareLoader from 'vue-spinner/src/SquareLoader.vue'

export default {
  name: 'full',
  components: {
    SquareLoader
  },
  data () {
    return {
      loading: true,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Whenever the site start, SquareLoader will be shown.
At Dashboard.vue i have some requests to get data.
Is there any way to update loading = false ( loading is belong to Main.vue ) from Dashboard.vue?

Comment: if you cant use $emit then alternative options are either use vuex or the event bus approach. Vuex way would be to move the loading state to the store and dispatch action from dashboard to update the value.